# What is the difference between letting nohup append to 'nohup.out' and explicitly redirecting it to a file?

Tags: bash, ssh, background-process, nohup

Consider the following scenario:

**tail.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -f test.txt
```

**invoke.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup ./tail.sh &
```

**invoke_explicitredirect.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup ./tail.sh > out.log &
```

Running both in a terminal has the same effect:

- I regain control of the terminal after running `./tail.sh`
- No output from `tail` appears on the terminal

However, when running it using `ssh` (e.g. `ssh <user>@<hostname> "<script>"`):

- `invoke_explicitredirect.sh` returns control to `ssh` (and terminates)
- `invoke.sh` hangs until I send a `SIGINT`

`man nohup` states that `nohup` will automatically redirect output to 'nohup.out' if possible:

```
If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if possible, '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise.
```

What is the difference between letting `nohup` append to `nohup.out` and explicitly redirecting the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard output is not a terminal when you launch the command remotely through ssh. Use the `-t` option with `ssh` to get the same behavior with both of your commands.

More details on ssh and nohup: http://snailbook.com/faq/background-jobs.auto.html (taken from the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

Comment: I'm not sure what happened. All I get is `Connection to <host> closed`, and no `nohup.out` file. If I add `echo test > out2.log` to both scripts, `out2.log` gets created, but still no `nohup.out`

Comment: Just tried it with `sleep` (`ssh <user>@<hostname> "<script>; sleep 1"`) and it worked. Looks like `ssh` was terminating too early.

Comment: What is standard output when `ssh` is used?

Comment: The remote command standard output is going to the ssh client input in both cases but when `-t` is used, it behaves like a terminal. Nohup has a different output handling depending on whether it is a terminal or not.

Comment: More details on `ssh` and `nohup`: http://www.snailbook.com/faq/background-jobs.auto.html (taken from the wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Comment: Added above comment to answer.